# Component identification, between USB-C switch IC and connector

Tags: usb, identification, usb-c

[image: PCB photo]

As the title really, can you identify this component?

It's on a line connecting a USB-C switch IC (PI3USB30532) to the USB-C connector and I believe the line is for Display port functionality.

How Critical are the values of this part as i have no way of finding them?

Comment: Sorry, it does help if you put the picture in before posting

Comment: No worries. Are there any markings on them you can discern?

Comment: They look like dual resistor networks - perhaps termination resistors. You could try measuring them with a multi-meter, see if you get approx. 50Ohm or 100Ohm across them.

Comment: No there are no markings on them.

Comment: I have measured them and was only getting 1 Ohm

Comment: Most likely in-line ESD protection devices as they have pads for ground connection. They could also be common mode chokes.

Answer (score 4):

This is an EMI choke. Take a closer look or check with a magnet - the body of this component is made of ferrite.

Comment: Agreed. Looks like a package with ESD protection built in. Something like [these](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/AWE0000/AWE0000C294.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

This component is called "Common-mode Choke". Example: Murata [DLP11TB800UL2L](https://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/products/emiconfun/mail/2011/09/28/en-20110928/l0114s0129dlp11.ashx).
The choke is placed into differential data line like this:

[image]

This CMC is meant to suppress common-mode ESD events and reduce unwanted emission (which may happen when the transmission line is not perfectly balanced).

See also [TDK offerings](https://product.tdk.com/info/en/products/emc/emc/cmf_cmc/technote/cmf-selection-guide.html) and typical use of individual chokes.

[image]

These components don't incude TVS elements, these packages have more than 4 pins.

Comment: Actually, the last picture from TDK is silly, USB2.0 don't have DC-decoupling caps. Funny, a typical marketoidal glitch.